# How to install Splint on Ubuntu 20.04 VM?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, make

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 VM running on Virtual Box. I'm trying to install Splint on this VM following the instructions on the website (http://splint.org/linux.html).

Point 5 of the instructions says to run `make install`. When I run it I obtain an error:

```
$ make install
cd . && /bin/bash /home/user/Downloads/splint-3.1.1/config/missing --run aclocal-1.6 
/home/user/Downloads/splint-3.1.1/config/missing: line 46: aclocal-1.6: command not found
WARNING: `aclocal-1.6' is needed, and you do not seem to have it handy on your
         system.  You might have modified some files without having the
         proper tools for further handling them.  Check the `README' file,
         it often tells you about the needed prerequirements for installing
         this package.  You may also peek at any GNU archive site, in case
         some other package would contain this missing `aclocal-1.6' program.
make: *** [Makefile:138: aclocal.m4] Error 1
```

I tried to solve this problem following [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33286344/11503700), without success. Then I removed the VM, created a new one and restarted the installation process till point 5, so the actual VM is clean.

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Is the `automake` package installed on your system?

Comment: @steeldriver No, should I install it?

Comment: I believe it should contain the requested `aclocal-1.16` so yes I suggest installing it

Comment: @steeldriver I installed it, still the same error

Comment: Did you re-run `./configure` after installing the package? or just jump straight to `make install`?

Comment: @steeldriver yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered I could also use `apt install splint`, and this worked without problems. Probably there's something wrong with the archive they provide, I wasn't able to complete the installation process following the instructions in the official webpage.